# What is the purpose of pushing empty objects into the adsbygoogle array in Adsense tags?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, adsense

This is the explanation from [their site](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.co.il/2013/07/an-async-script-for-adsense-tagging.html):

> A call to adsbygoogle.push(), which instructs us to fill in the first unfilled slot.

But what is the adsbygoogle array used for in the javascript code?

Here is a sample ad tag (see the javascript line at the end):

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 data-ad-slot="yyyyyyyyyy"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || [])` basically means "if `adsbygoogle` does not exist yet, create it". Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: @FelixKling, No, I asked about this comment from their site: "A call to adsbygoogle.push(), which instructs us to fill in the first unfilled slot."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The script which actually loads AdSense ads, adsbygoogle.js, is loaded asynchronously (i.e. via a <script async> tag).  The call to adsbygoogle.push() is a way for the page to tell the script that there is an ad slot to be filled, using code that can be executed either before or after that async-loaded script has executed.

If adsbygoogle.js has not yet loaded, then adsbygoogle.push({}) makes the adsbygoogle array one element longer, which effectively increments the count of how many ad slots are sitting around waiting for adsbygoogle.js to pay attention to them.  When adsbygoogle.js loads, it iterates through that queue, processing one ad slot for each queue entry.

Now the clever bit: Once adsbygoogle.js loads, it replaces adsbygoogle.push with a function that causes it to immediately process the new slot.  This means adsbygoogle.js doesn't need to poll the DOM for the addition of new slots needing processing.  (On modern browsers you could do this with a DOM Mutation Observer, but adsbygoogle predates this.)

This has mostly explained why you do a push() for each slot.  As for why you push an *empty object,* the answer by @JustcallmeDrago gives a good hint: The object you're pushing can contain some other configuration information about the slot, but the empty object {} is a nice short default, and means "fill the first unfilled slot, using the configuration data given by its tag in the DOM."

Answer (score 3):

Without delving into the actual adsbygoogle.js code, I believe it is simply setting up an array of objects which hold data related to each ad on the page. In the article, it is mentioned that part of using the tag is to include:

> A script, which ... is loaded asynchronously

One of the articles that is linked (Frontend Single Point of Failure) mentions that placing a `<script>` tag that requests a file can make the entire page fail if it times out. What is going on here is the JavaScript that is inserted along with each tag adds an object (which can specify parameters, see below) to the array `window.adsbygoogle`, which will be used by adsbygoogle.js when it is loaded asynchronously later.

Certain parameters can be added to the objects that are `.push()`ed in. An example from [here (expand the A/B testing section)](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en):

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
    data-ad-client="ca-publisher-id">
</ins>
<script>
    if (Math.random() < .5) {
      mySlotId = '1234567890';
    } else {
      mySlotId = '2345678901';
    }
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
      params: { google_ad_slot: mySlotId }
    });
</script>
```

Specifically, `{ params: { google_ad_slot: mySlotId } }` specifies additional parameters for adsbygoogle.js to act upon when it finds that respective ad.

Comment: Does the following comment helps explaining their method?
"A call to adsbygoogle.push(), which instructs us to fill in the first unfilled slot."

Comment: Not really. From their explanation on what the tag code is _doing_, I cannot really tell what adsbygoogle.js is doing _with_ it. Since adsbygoogle.js is not loaded when the .push() code runs, window.adsbygoogle cannot be anything besides a plain array. There's no magic happening there. Instead, adsbygoogle.js uses that array later in some way.

Comment: So is it some kind of counter that can count the tags while the page is loading?

Comment: No, each ad on the page has an object in that array. adsbygoogle.js looks at each object and if it sees additional parameters in it (e.g. "params" above), it can change its behavior. It basically configures each ad according to what's in the ad's object.

Comment: So why are the empty objects inserted, how do they relate to the ad ins elements and to the configured slots?

Answer (score 1):

Something_ is pushed to an empty array, that goes out of scope quickly, no harm, little overhead and —the key reason— **short to write**. Here is a much longer, clumsy way to write the same:

```
if (typeof window.adsbygoogle !== 'undefined')
{
  window.adsbygoogle.push({});
}
```

If `adsbygoogle` *is* defined (aka the async loaded script happens to have arrived), the push() is an entirely different function: written by google and doing a lot more than a simple *add-to-array*.

———

The fact that ´[window.]adsbygoogle´ is guaranteed to be initialized (with [], if the real thing does not exist yet) might be a way of flagging (to the *async-not-yet-loaded*) google script **‘there's at least one ad around’**.

Comment: This does not work. when adsbygoogle is undefined it doesn't do anything. I tried alert(isAdsenseNotLoaded); only works when the object is defined.